# How to index subtitles with Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to implement a search engine using Lucene. I have subtitles as corpus. I parsed them and converted them to the following format:

```
timestamp0   sentence0
timestamp1   sentence1
timestamp2   sentence2
.
.
.
```

I implemented a basic indexing and searching application using only sentences in the document. However what I want to achieve is to make Lucene return the timestamps of sentences as well. In other words, I want my search engine to be able to say when a certain phrase occurs in a movie. Could I achieve that using Lucene? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, just store the date as a separate field in the document.  What's the problem?

Comment: There are lots of lines in a document, hence lots of timestamps and sentences. I saw examples where a document contains several different fields. However what I have is a document with 2 same fields in each line. Is there a similar example you can direct me to?

Comment: It's up to you what you consider to be a Lucene document.  It doesn't have to be a file, it should be whatever is the logical unit of data you want to search in and retrieve.  I recommend, for this use case, that a "document" is a line, and that document contains a single timestamp and a single textual line (and other fields, if appropriate, of course).

Comment: That's a great idea. Can I group the searching results using Lucene or should I do it manually? In the search results, I want to show to user the movies with summary being a few matching subtitle lines.

Comment: If you have a field for the movie title, you can Sort on that field, instead of by relevance.  If your query is relatively simple. losing sorting by relevance may not be a big deal.  See Lucene's [Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html), used like:  `indexSearcher.search(query,maxResults,new Sort(new SortField("title",SortField.Type.STRING));`